# Why does the character "&ndash;" become a "?" after added to JSON string and posted to REST web service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring-mvc

I have a web page with an edit form populated with data from the database.

I'm having problems with one character, an escaped n-dash character ... `&ndash;`

The input field looks like this ...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="LocalName"
   name="LocalName" value="&ndash;" />
```

(NOTE: The value is the string read from the database, then escaped using Apache Commons library like so ... `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(sValue);` ... if I don't escape it, it will display as `value="?"`.)

When I click the 'Save' button, I put all the form data in a JSON string like this ...

```
$("#doSaveEntityButton").click(function() {

        var formData = {
            
            Name:$('#Name').val(),
            Region:$('#Region').val(),
            LocalName:$('#LocalName').val()

        }

        var sJSON = JSON.stringify(formData);
        alert("001: sJSON = "+sJSON);
```

At this point, the text displayed in the alert looks like this ...

```
001: sJSON = {"Name":"Antarctica","Region":"Antarctica","LocalName":"?"}
```

Notice The LocalName value is a "?" character instead of the n-dash or even "–".

INTERESTING NOTE! I just noticed that when I copy and pasted this text from the alert dialog box to here, the character is displaying properly ... like so ...

```
001: sJSON = {"Name":"Antarctica","Region":"Antarctica","LocalName":"–"}
```

That's interesting, but I still have my problem.

My problem is ... I then POST the sJSON string version of formData to my web service like so ...

```
    var sJSON = JSON.stringify(formData);
    alert("001: sJSON = "+sJSON);
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/myapplication/json/saveentity", 
            data : sJSON,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

        success : function(msg) {
            /* ... */
        },
        error : function(msg) {
            displayMessages(msg.responseJSON.messages);
        },
            done : function(e) {
        }
    });
});
```

On the web service side, it appears as a "?" character.  The n-dash has been lost.

My Java Spring MVC web service looks like this ...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json/app/{appId}/{entityDefId}/saveentity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> saveEntity(@PathVariable("appId") int appId, @PathVariable("entityDefId") int entityDefId, @RequestBody String json) throws Exception {
```

Everything works fine with all of the other types of data.

What am I doing wrong with that n-dash?

Comment: So why is `&ndash;` being set as `value`?

Comment: The "n-dash" character is the value that's in the database.  It's actually from the MySQL "World" sample database.  The "Antartica" row from the "Country" table ... here's a screenshot of the row: https://i.imgur.com/gL7QG9k.png

Comment: Should the value be something other than `&ndash;` ?  I'm getting that value by escaping the original string by using Apache Commons library like so ... `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(sValue);` ... is the problem that the character in the value field should not be escaped like that?

Comment: @charlietfl Just FYI, I just tried not escaping with StringEscapeUtils and that way it will display as  `value="?"` ... so didn't work

Comment: Values should be regular text (or empty), not html entities

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks ... that makes sense to me.  But in that case, any idea how I can populate the value with the correct character instead of getting a "?" (which is what I get when I don't use `escapeHtml4(sValue)`

Comment: Remove the `-` from fields that only have that as value perhaps?

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the help, but removing the character won't work for me, as when they click 'save' the new version (minus the character) will get pushed back to the database.  I'd be modifying the data without the user intending to do that.  Also, I expect I'd be able to reproduce this using other `&;` characters too.  I'll need to find a way to handle this.

Comment: What I meant though was remove it from db, unless it is a default value which would seem wierd

Comment: Thanks, wish I could just remove it but I'm building a tool for end users and I have no control over what data they put in their database.  I'm actually testing with the MySQL World example database because there's a lot of different types of data in there.